# Postgres: Create role in one line

Tags: postgresql, command-line

I want to create a role/user in one line. Here's what I tried:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'createuser my_app with createdb login password 'my_password';'
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "with" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "createdb" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "login" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "password" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "'my_password';'" ignored
psql: FATAL:  database "my_app" does not exist
```

In place of `createuser` I have also tried `create user` and `create role`, but regardless, I get the same error. I'm on *Windows* with *(PostgreSQL) 9.6.2*

What am I doing wrong?

---

Update:

I tried using double quotes, but for some reason, postgres doesn't seem to like my double quotes. Using double quotes inside of single quotes mysteriously works -> Thanks @Laurenz

```
psql -U postgres -c "createuser my_app with createdb login password 'my_password';"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createuser"
LINE 1: createuser my_app with createdb login password 'my_password'...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`createuser` is not an SQL command, so that won't work.

`CREATE USER` is correct, but you can't nest single quotes in single quotes like that.

It should be

```
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER my_app CREATEDB PASSWORD 'my_password'"
```